# validate if a row is selected in telerik grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Is there a way to know if a row is selected in telerik grid? As of Now, I have a function which gives me the selected row value. But It returns undefined if nothing is selected. Hence I want a better way know if a row is selected or not. Is there an inbuild telerik method "isSelected" or something which can tell us if anything is selected in a telerik grid?

```
function projectGrid_onRowSelect(e) {
    rowValue = e.srcElement.innerText;
};
```

Comment: Using the debugger tool (such as FireBug for FireFox and similar built-in ones for other browsers, usually F12 default key) investigate the elements (Right-click a row and select "Inspect Element" or similar in the right-click menu), I think telerik marks rows with classes. You can use the debugger tool to watch the markup change while you select a row and see if it does add/remove a class when selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in method but you could try next code

```
function IsSelected(gridId)
{
  return  $("#" + gridId + " tbody tr.t-state-selected").length > 0;
}
```